# Matching within a column and spanning past multiple columns with Pandas

Tags: pandas

Good afternoon!
I was hoping for some help with matching. This is an example DF, but for the sake of argument, I'm trying to match movie info. Here's the DF:
[image: DF]

My goal here is to use Film ID #999 (the last row) as an input to find out which of the *other* films are most similar to them in two ways:

1. In the description, so we can see what's most similar to how it's being described.
2. Throughout the other columns. If one film has the same director, genre, publisher and nearly everything else except for the release year, that'd be helpful to know.

Here's the code for the data prep.

```
#importing packages
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pandas as pd 

#Building the df
data = {
    "Film ID": [239, 133, 323, 120, 999],
    "Movie Title": ["This scary movie", "This sci-fi movie", "This action movie", "This other horror movie", "The test movie"],
    "Description": ["So scary, you'll cry!", "We found life on Mars.", "The bad guys came back!", "The boogeyman is REAL!", "Just a test."],
    "Director": ["John Smith", "Jane Doe", "John Johnson", "Jane Doe", "Richard Richardson"],
    "Movie Setting": ["Chicago", "Chicago", "NYC", "NYC", "LA"],
    "Genre": ["Horror", "Sci-Fi", "Action", "Horror", "Sci-Fi"],
    "Publisher": ["Paramount Studios", "Walt Disney Studios", "Warner Bros", "Pixar", "Pixar"],
    "Release Year": ["2021", "1998", "2022", "2011", "2015"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df #showing the df
```

My issue now is trying to create the function and I started with the description matching. Here's the formula as I've been working on it:

```
def movie_match(film_id): #building a function where you input what you want to match against.
    id = df.loc[df['Film ID'] == film_id] #renaming it for easier access
    matching_df = df.copy() #Making a new df that only exists in this function.
    matching_df['Match %'] = '0%'
    matching_df['Description %'] = '0%' #Creating new columns, one for overall match %, the other for just the description.
    for row in matching_df.iterrows():
        matching_df.loc[matching_df['Film ID'] == row]['Match %'] = fuzz.token_set_ratio(str(df.loc[df['Film ID'] == id]['Description']), str(df.loc[df['Film ID'] == row]['Description']))
        matching_df = matching_df.sort_values(by='Description %')
#    matching_df = matching_df[['Film ID', 'Movie Title']] #Removing unused columns.
    print(matching_df, id)
    
movie_match(229887)
```

This resulted in an error:
[image: Error]

Now I understand it came from Line 7 of that screenshot and it was because I used the term "ID", because I'm having trouble how to bypass the multidimensional key and the other Google searches on this error code isn't helping, and I'm not quite sure, even conceptually, how to tackle the other match where I go through each row.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, with data prep you provide, what should the expected result look like?